# Rails doesn't save a form value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a new column to a table in my rails database, called zoom. I have a form which allows the user to update the value of "zoom".

Pressing the submit value on the form causes the page to send a put request with the correct value for "zoom", and the correct values for all the other data in the table.

All of the other data saves, but "zoom" does not, instead retaining it's default value. Rails flashes a message to say the save has been successful.

What can I do to diagnose this problem?

Help much appreciated,  Jimmy

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your code. Kinda like diagnosing a decease over a phone.

Comment: did you add the column to the table through a rails migration, or by hand in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `attr_accessible :zoom` in the model where zoom is defined.

Comment: Just thought of looking in the log, this is what I see:  Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Comment: OK, me going mental. I'd just used the wrong variable name in attr_accessible

Comment: I think adding the attr_accessible will intercept the message before method missing picks up the column name.

Comment: remove :zoom from attr_protected ?

Answer (score 0):

In this [thread](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38445), they suggest adding: `attr_accessible :tag_names` in your model. Give it a try!